# Proof of convergence in distribution of a discrete random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof of convergence in distribution of a discrete random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246955/proof-of-convergence-in-distribution-of-a-discrete-random-variable)

I'm working on a question on "convergence in distribution" and I appreciate if you could guide me on how to approach this question:

Here is the question:

Let $X_n$ be integer-valued random variables. Show that $X_n \rightarrow^w X_{\infty}$ converges in distribution if and only if $\mathrm{Pr}(X_n = m) \rightarrow \mathrm{Pr}(X_{\infty} = m)$ for each $m$.

I appreciate your help.