# Convergence in Distribution implies Convergence in Expectation?

Tags: probability, statistics

I need some help the following problem:

> Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be a sequence of random variables such that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in distribution, where $X \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$. Let the function $f(x)=I_{(1,10)}(x)$ be the indicator function. Do we have $$E[f(X_n)]\to E[f(X)]?$$Hint: $X_n=X+1/n.$

What I tried is the following: 
$$E[f(X_n)]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}I_{(1,10)}(x)e^{-\lambda} {{\lambda}^{x+1/n} \over {(x+1/n)!}}$$ and $$E[f(X)]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}I_{(1,10)}(x)e^{-\lambda} {{\lambda}^{x} \over {x!}}.$$
Then evaluate their difference: 
$E[f(X_n)]-E[f(X)]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty I_{(1,10)}(x)e^{-\lambda}\big( {{\lambda}^{x+1/n} \over {(x+1/n)!}}-{{\lambda}^{x} \over {x!}}\big)$.

But I don't feel this will give something helpful if I move on. Am I on the right track? Or how to solve this problem in some other way?

Comment: I'm afraid $E[f(X_n)] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}I_{(1,10)}(k+\frac{1}{n})e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$, be careful with your notation

Answer (score 1):

Why are you considering the *sum* of your rv's? Also, the statement of the problem does not say that the r.v's in the sequence follow the Poisson, only that the sequence converges to a Poisson. But I will assume that the $X_n$'s are discrete.

Your $f$ is bounded. If it was also continuous, this result would be part of the "Portmanteau Theorem" (or Lemma). Now that $f$ is not continuous, we make use of the fact that $E(I_{A}(x)) = P(x \in A)$

So the question can be re-written as

$$P(X_n\in (1,10)) \rightarrow ? \; P(X\in (1,10))$$
Since you have used parentheses for $(1,10)$, I assume that $(1,10) = \{1,2,...,10\}$ (although it doesn't make any difference). So we require whether

$$\sum_{1}^{10}P(X_n=i) \rightarrow? \sum_{1}^{10}P(X=i)$$

But you have already assumed that $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$. Convergence in distribution for discrete rv's is equivalent (see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246955/proof-of-convergence-in-distribution-of-a-discrete-random-variable))  to the fact that $$P(X_n=i) \rightarrow P(X=i)\qquad \forall i$$

Since by convergence in distribution we have essentially assumed that for each point in the support, the **pmf** converges to a corresponding constant (the limiting probability for each $i$), the sum of some of these points in the support (LHS of the question) will converge to the sum of these constants (RHS of the question). QED.